# React Hook select multiple items with icons

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to implement a popover with many items where a user can multi select them. When a user clicks a item, a font-awesome icon is shown to the right.

A user is able to select multiple items and an icon is shown on the right to show it has been checked. This icon toggles when clicking. My problem is my event handler is tied to all the items and whenever I click one, all gets checked.

I am new to hook and react.  I am also trying to assign the Id of the selected item in an array. It won't append.

```
const SettingsComponent = (props) => {
const urlStofTyper = stofTyperUrl; 
const stofTyper = [];
const [isPopoverOpen, setPopoverOpen] = useState(false);

const [isItemChecked, setItemChecked] = useState(false);

const [error, setError] = useState(null);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(null);
const [stoftype, setStoftyper] = useState({ DataList: [] });

const toggle = () => setPopoverOpen(!isPopoverOpen);

const sectionClicked = (e) => {
setItemChecked(!isItemChecked);
let secId = e.target.parentNode.getAttribute("data-section");   
if (!isItemChecked) {
    stofTyper.push(secId);
   } else {
    stofTyper.filter((sec) => sec == secId);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
fetchStoftyper({ setError, setLoading, setStoftyper });
}, []);

const fetchStoftyper = async ({ setError, setLoading, setStoftyper }) => {
try {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await Axios(urlStofTyper);
    const allStofs = response.data;
    setLoading(false);
    setStoftyper(allStofs);
  } catch (error) {
    setLoading(false);
    setError(error);
  }
};

return (
<React.Fragment>
  <div className='list-header-icons__fontawesome-icon' id='PopoverClick'>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCog} />
  </div>
  <Popover
    isOpen={isPopoverOpen}
    placement='bottom'
    toggle={toggle}
    target='PopoverClick'>
    <PopoverHeader>formatter</PopoverHeader>
    <div className='popover-body'>
      <ul className='individual-col--my-dropdown-menu-settings'>
        {stoftype.DataList.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.Id} className='section-items'>
            <a
              onClick={sectionClicked}                 
              className='dropdown-item'                 

              data-section={item.Sections[0].SectionId}
              data-format={
                item.Formats.length > 0
                  ? item.Formats[0].FormatId
                  : ""
              }
              aria-selected='false'>
              <span className='formatter-name'>
                {item.Name}
              </span>
              {isItemChecked && (
                <span className='formatter-check-icon'>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} size='lg' />
                </span>
              )}
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </Popover>
</React.Fragment>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have a solution for my own question. Even though, I did not need above solution but I though it would be a good practice to try solve it. Popover is not relevant as that was used only as a wrapper. The below solution can still be placed in a Popover.

CodeSandBox link: [Demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactdropdownmultiselect-l8cg7) using Class component, I will try to re-write this using hooks as soon as possible.

This solution dependency is Bootstrap 4 and Fontawesome.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Cars from "./DataSeed";

class DropDownWithSelect extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggleDropdown = this.toggleDropdown.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      isDropDownOpen: false,
      idsOfItemClicked: []
    };
  }

  toggleDropdown = evt => {
    this.setState({
      isDropDownOpen: !this.state.isDropDownOpen
    });
  };

  toggleItemClicked = id => {
    this.setState(state => {
      const idsOfItemClicked = state.idsOfItemClicked.includes(id)
        ? state.idsOfItemClicked.filter(x => x !== id)
        : [...state.idsOfItemClicked, id];

      return {
        idsOfItemClicked
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="dropdown">
        <button
          onClick={this.toggleDropdown}
          className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
          type="button"
          id="dropdownMenuButton"
          data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false"
        >
          Dropdown button
        </button>
        {this.state.isDropDownOpen && (
          <div
            className="dropdown-menu show"
            aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"
          >
            {Cars.map(x => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={x.id}
                  onClick={() => this.toggleItemClicked(x.id)}
                  className="dropdown-item d-inline-flex justify-content-between"
                >
                  <span className="d-flex"> {x.name} </span>
                  <span className="d-flex align-self-center">
                    {this.state.idsOfItemClicked.includes(x.id) && (
                      <i className="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" />
                    )}
                  </span>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default DropDownWithSelect;
```

Data i.e., ./DataSeed

```
    const cars = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "BMW",
    cost: 450000
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Audi",
    cost: 430000
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Mercedes",
    cost: 430000
  }
];

export default cars;
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are using one boolean variable to check if the icon should be displayed, it will not work because every item in your `DataList` should have it's own individual indicator.

One of the possible solution is to use `new Map()` for this purposes and store `item.id` as and index and `true/false` as a value, so your selected state will be something like this:

```
Map(3) {1 => true, 2 => true, 3 => false}
```

After that you can check if you should display your icon as follow:

```
!!selected.get(item.id)
```

It will return true if the value in your HashTable is true, and false if it's false or doesn't exist at all. That should be enough to implement the feature you asked for.

For the real example you can check [flatlist-selectable section from official Facebook docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#basic-example) They show how to achieve multi-selection using this technique. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Nikolai, thanks for giving your time & effort. I will look into it and come back.